# $http.post not working in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to post some movie data, while using $http.post it shows new record is inserted but while listing the movies it only shows the id's not the other fields.

Here is my app.js,

```js
myApp.controller("addMovieCtrl",function($scope,$http,$window,$mdToast,$mdDialog){
  $scope.submitForm = function(){ 
  $scope.movies = [];
        $scope.movies.push({
   title  : $scope.mtitle,
   director : $scope.mdirector,
   genre  : $scope.mgenre,
   releaseYear : $scope.myear,
  });
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies/',
          data    : $scope.movies, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
          .success(function(data) {
               $mdToast.show(
         $mdToast.simple()
           .textContent(data.message)
           .position($scope.getToastPosition())
           .hideDelay(2000)
       );             
          }).error(function(err){
            $mdToast.show(
         $mdToast.simple()
           .textContent(err)
           .position($scope.getToastPosition())
           .hideDelay(2000)
       ); 
          });
  $scope.mtitle = ''; //clear the input after adding
  $scope.mdirector = '';
  $scope.mgenre = '';
  $scope.myear = '';
 };
  });
```

and this is my view page,

```html
  <body ng-controller="addMovieCtrl" ng-app="myApp">    
    <div>
    <div class="edit_data">
      <form class="form-register" name="register" ng-submit="submitForm()" novalidate>
              <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="first-name" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="mtitle" required>
              <label for="first-name">Movie Title</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="last-name" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="mdirector" required>
              <label for="last-name">Director</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">            
              <input id="last-name" type="text" class="validate" ng-model="mgenre" required>
              <label for="last-name">Genre</label>
             </div>
             <div class="input-field col s6">            
              <input id="last-name"  type="number" class="validate" ng-model="myear" required>
              <label for="last-name">Release Year</label>
             </div>
             <!-- <div class="input-field col s6">
             <md-datepicker ng-model="mdate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
              </div> -->
              <br />
              <div class="spacer text-center">
                 <button ng-disabled="form-register.$invalid" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">
                 <i class="material-icons left">done</i> Done
                 </button>
                 <button type="button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
                 <i class="material-icons left">clear</i>Cancel
                 </button>
              </div>
             </form>
      </div>
      <br/>  
  </div>
```

Here is the working fiddle - [jsfiddle.net/5zzpL8om](http://jsfiddle.net/5zzpL8om)

while i try with the rest client same is happening.

Comment: did you use post form by postman ?

Comment: where is the list code , where you list the movies

Comment: just check this url - http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies/.

Comment: this is just the json...are you saying that while posting data, you do not receive other fields in the backend ?

Comment: can you post some working fiddle?

Comment: @gaurav5430 : do you notice that in the json the last object has only _id and _v . but while posting the $scope.movies it has complete data.

Comment: @gaurav5430: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q4wxxxho/

Comment: @gaurav5430 : This is new fiddle its working - http://jsfiddle.net/5zzpL8om/

Comment: how are you handling it on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you did not mean to send an array back to server instead you wanted to send only the current data.

I have tried this and it is working:

```
var dataObj = {
            title       : $scope.mtitle,
            director    : $scope.mdirector,
            genre       : $scope.mgenre,
            releaseYear : $scope.myear,
        };

        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies/',
          data    : dataObj, //forms user object
          //headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
         })
```

here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5zzpL8om/4/

i have also checked the results on:
http://movieapp-sitepointdemos.rhcloud.com/api/movies/